# blueimp jQuery-File-Upload basic usage not working

Tags: jquery, blueimp

I am trying to use basic plugin of blueimp jQuery file upload plugin like below according to their [document](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

I have added these three js libraries as well

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
```

But it's still not working, What is the wrong thing that i have done?

Comment: You need to add the `data-url` attribute to your file input which holds the URL of the server-side script which saves the file. See the documentation for more details: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for your comment. I will check it